# How to Verify Sharding?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to shard MongoDB. I am done with Sharding configuration, but I am not sure how to verify if sharding is functional.

How do i check whether my data is get sharded? Is there a query to verify/validate the shards?

Comment: Enabled sharding in what, exactly?  Configured backups using what method, exactly?

Comment: you expect us to answer an unclear question with that many question marks?????

Comment: MySQL doesn't have sharding.  MySQL doesn't have backups to be configured.  And now you've mentioned MongoDB.  Perhaps you have mis-tagged your question?

Comment: Hi Charles,I am using mongo-db for sharding......I cant understand how to check the shard database.... please give  precise information...Dont give the default mongodb site link to verify...I know u might have known about mongodb so, please update me with the precise explanation of distributed mongodb sharding & query to check the shard databases...........

Thanks,
sampath...

Comment: I've updated the tag for your question so people that know about MongoDB will see it.  Your previous tag meant that only MySQL people could see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB has detailed documentation on Sharding here ...

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction

To anwser you question (I think), see the portion on the [config Servers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction#ShardingIntroduction-ConfigServers) ...

> Each config server has a complete copy
>   of all chunk information.  A two-phase
>   commit is used to ensure the
>   consistency of the configuration data
>   among the config servers.

Basically, it is the config server's job to make sure everything get sharded ... *correctly*.

Also, there are system collections you can [query](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Configuring+Sharding) ...

> db.runCommand( { listshards : 1 } );

Lots of help in the prez below too ...

http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/mongodb-sharding-internals

http://www.10gen.com/video/mongosv2010/sharding

Comment: I may not exactly understand what you are asking for, but seems to me that is exactly what the config servers do FOR you, so you don't need to query and check if the data is stored ... that is THEIR job. There really shouldn't be any need for you to query it manually yourself?

Comment: Hi, We are using the Mongo-db-sharding for the purpose of performance Enhancement.....  According to the sharding concept it will split the same data store it in the configured shards-server...Now how do i check the sharded data???....can u understand ???...

Answer (score 16):

You can also execute a simple command on your mongos router :

```
> use admin
> db.printShardingStatus();
```

which should output informations about your shards, your sharded dbs and your sharded collection as mentioned in the [mongodb documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Administration#ShardingAdministration-ViewShardingDetails)

```
sharding version: { "_id" : 1, "version" : 2 }
  shards:
      { "_id" : ObjectId("4bd9ae3e0a2e26420e556876"), "host" : "localhost:30001" }
      { "_id" : ObjectId("4bd9ae420a2e26420e556877"), "host" : "localhost:30002" }
      { "_id" : ObjectId("4bd9ae460a2e26420e556878"), "host" : "localhost:30003" }

  databases:
    { "name" : "admin", "partitioned" : false,
          "primary" : "localhost:20001",
          "_id" : ObjectId("4bd9add2c0302e394c6844b6") }
    my chunks

        { "name" : "foo", "partitioned" : true,
          "primary" : "localhost:30002",
          "sharded" : { "foo.foo" : { "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "unique" : false } },
          "_id" : ObjectId("4bd9ae60c0302e394c6844b7") }
        my chunks
        foo.foo { "_id" : { $minKey : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { $maxKey : 1 } }
                  on : localhost:30002 { "t" : 1272557259000, "i" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether you are conencted to a sharded cluster or not: 
`db.isMaster()` can be used to detect that you are connected to a sharding router (`mongos`).

If `db.isMaster().msg` is "isdbgrid", you are connected to a sharded instance.

[db.isMaster()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/isMaster/#sharded-instances) can be run without authentication.

For checking the details of the shards, [`sh.status()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.status/) also works, which has the same output as `db.printShardingStatus();` works.